# Disable DHCP for one interface only

Tags: networking, windows-10, dhcp, network-interface

On my PC I have one Ethernet port that I use for network testing purposes (testing Openflow switches). For that I want that port to only send the packets that I tell it to (using packet generator software).

I got rid off almost everything, except the DHCP. I don't want to disable DHCP completely, because I need it to work on the other interfaces. Is there a way to disable DHCP and DHCPv6 on a per-interface basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure a static IP address for that interface – or disable the IPv4 & IPv6 protocols entirely.

Comment: Yep, just use a static IP, gateway, DNS, etc. and Windows won't try to look up anything using DHCP.

Comment: That's a good point, didn't think of that. Thanks a lot!